# How do I create background image in Google docs

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

How do I create an image behind text in Google docs (the text editor part)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is to insert the background image and text as a drawing (insert > drawing).

The drawing tools allow ordering of layers unlike the normal editor.

Comment: Not perfect, but does the job! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Putting text into a drawing *dramatically* lowers the quality of the text during printing. The best way might be to print a sheet with the watermark, and then print again with a normal document over the top!

Comment: That's true this would be certain less than ideal. You might be able to get better results by ensuring the image is the exact size and resolution for your document to avoid resizing it out of the drawing tools.

Comment: Google has now introduced a new "Watermark" feature that does the job perfectly.  See Insert->Watermark.  It even allows precise positioning outside the margins and sizing.